# How to simulate connection timeout scenario with Wiremock

Tags: integration-testing, karate, spring-boot-test, wiremock

I need to write integration test using karate and spring boot to simulate connection timeout scenario. I am using Wiremock as mock server.

I have written a  primary service and internally it calls two downstream apis.

To emulate this behavior, have set resttemplate timeouts as below.

connectTimeout=10

readTimeout=5000

I am able to simulate read timeouts using fixed delays in wiremock, but unable to do same for connection timeout. I have tried CONNECTION_RESET_BY_PEER fault as well but it throws NoSuchMethod Exception.

Is there any way in Wiremock where we can set its connect timeout as well. I have read docs but could not find any. Using version: '2.8.0'.

Simply stopping the server before test case doesnt look feasable.

Code: 
feature file:

```
Scenario: To validate the connection establishment issue with downstream API
Given path '/exampleuri'
And header X-SAMPLE-ID = 'xyz'
And header Authorization = tokenBearer.generateToken()
And header X-Forwarder-For = '10.0.0.127'
And request '{"subject":"My Example Subject"}'
When method POST
Then status 500

 WireMockServer wireMockServer =
  new WireMockServer(
      wireMockConfig().port(32434).usingFilesUnderDirectory("src/test/resources"));

 /** Start wiremock. */

    public void startWiremock() {
    wireMockServer.start();
  }


/** Stop wiremock. */
  public void stopWiremock() {
    wireMockServer.stop();
  }
```

Mapping:

```
{
    "request": {
    "urlPath": "/provider/user",
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
      "Accept": {
        "contains": "application/json"
      },
      "Content-Type": {
        "contains": "application/json"
      },
      "match-Id": {
        "contains": "befbe34"
      },
      "Authorization": {
        "contains": "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IlRJQUFfQVMtU2lnbiJ9.eyJhZGdyb3VwcyI6IkNOPWZHTEJJQkROVEVTVCxPVT1Hcm91cHMsT1U9R0xCLERDPUlOVFJBTkVULERDPUJBUkNBUElOVCxEQz1jb20iLCJzdWIiOiJzeXNUSUFBQVNCQUVURVNUIiwiZXhwIjoxNTYwMzkwNzcwLCJzY29wZSI6W10sImNsaWVudF9pZCI6IklCRE5DTElFTlQiLCJpc3MiOiJUSUFBLUFTIiwiYXVkIjoiSUJETiJ9.AaPSalG1PskW_h3-vj-oI-d73Vuk-vZDEu4feXemj_2uVUQ8uMybz-288v2u9kh3Ba9aMhHR6n6hgzTf4DlsDYBFgqVPvJ4vjqt2r7pCpNoSfIUN2kwIKCsspZeOcKMNPRFbiQf4KgpxZCFPwrGCW7bnTWc4WqBXUyaT7SvxXoyN9iVbA1pCIP7tcXGgUyKh0rglX45QSw03HPs7JphIMi5QUGYUzmCC7GDe8ZUg1VMFALw1FBDr86Eyxvyz8xkX90_7os6rVJKcfjKADg7IV6nAE8xC2-zvXR992-wXcLFWOF7ASAszZQrb5JIXchFc-2tH_H44Cm3KkFverxJwIQ"
      }
    },
    "queryParameters": {
      "userId": {
        "equalTo": "1234567"
      },
      "indicator": {
        "equalTo": "true"
      }
    }
  },
  "response": {
    "fault": "CONNECTION_RESET_BY_PEER"
  }
  }
```

Even after setting 10 as connect timeout in resttemplate, its able to connect to wiremock server.
Please suggest some solutions.

Comment: in case you were not aware, karate has a mock capability as well that can replace wiremock: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-netty

Comment: Yeah, I know. But currently we are using Karate with wiremock for this release. Later on we might move to karate-netty. But, right now need some solution for this scenario. Thanks Peter.

Comment: sure, all the best. can't help you here. but am confused. karate is making the HTTP requests right ? so why are you bringing resttemplate into the picture ?

Comment: Can you add the mapping rule that is triggered?

Comment: @Peter: Karate calls /register which is my api endpoint and internally this api uses resttemplate to call downstream apis. So, I need to simulate the connection error scenario with downstream systems.

Comment: @A.Kootstra: Mapping provided in description.

Comment: In the description you're mentioning that you're using 2.8.0. Have you tried using the most recent version? At the time of writing this is 2.25.1.